# What is the lightest known metal?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

what do we mean by lightest? I mean, 10 g of aluminum is just as light 10 g of steel. So what's the point? [image]

Comment: I'm sorry but that should be least dense instead of lightest. There's something wrong with the question. I will fix it for the next update of the app. Thank you.

Comment: Lithium is the metal with the lowest density you could also quibble that steel is an alloy . It would be better to say 'which of these materials has the lowest density ?'.

Comment: Can someone provide sone context here?  What is this from?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a very well worded question. One problem is that the definition of a 'metal' is not entirely unambiguous depending on context, for example a cosmologist might consider anything which isn't hydrogen or helium to be a metal and chemists might disagree amongst themselves about exactly what is and is not a metal.

In engineering there is also the complication that the majority of metals are really metal alloys, normally this difference is trifling but of you are talking about 'known metals' that implies a chemistry type definition. A physicist may argue that hydrogen has metallic phases under certain conditions.

Also in the context using 'lightest' is actually ok as chemists and physicists  will talk of heavy and light elements, although in an engineering context using density is less ambiguous as engineers are more interested in ratios between density and strength etc.

A much less ambiguous way to phrase the question would be 'which of the following materials has the lowest density ?'.